# How to share a class object across all inherited class instances without instantiating it again?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, python-decorators

I want to share an utility object across my whole project without instantiating it more than once. It's basically something like a logger, database connection or browser window. I want the same object id in any instance of any class alive.

In my understanding that is what class variables are used for, but when I declare my utilities as a class variable within my parent class, it's being instantiated as soon as the parent class is being called the first time. That's not what I want. I want it to be initiated by hand, but I do not want to initialize it again every time a child is born while the new born child should be able to use it.

My design looks like this:

**Utility class**

```
class Utils:
    def utility_1(self):
        print("Do something")
```

**Parent class**

```
class Parent:

    utility = Utils.utility_1()
```

**Child class**

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def use_utility_1(self):
        self.utility_1(self.x)
```

The parent class as well as child class need to be able to use it. Everything I read about decorators etc. is going beyond or a are not the thing I need - at least in my understanding.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want differently. You *already* "instantiate" the object assigned to ``utility`` (actually, you don't – you call an unbound method and do some other wrong things, but those are probably typos) by hand. What's stopping you from doing so at another point of your program?

Comment: If you use the super() method it should work as expected : **super().utility_1(self.x)**

Comment: No need for super() here.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to clarify what you are actually asking about? Since the code as shown is broken, it's not clear whether you are asking about how to immediately fix *the code* or how instead to change *the design*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Could you please explain what you mean with "other wrong things"? In addition: can't also find any typos. As you might expect, I'm not very exerienced in oop. In case of a browser window / webdriver for instance, I only want one and it should be stay the same over the whole session.

Comment: ``utility = Utils.utility_1()`` calls an *unbound* method and thus fails; even if it would work, it would assign ``utility = None`` in the end. ``Child.use_utility_1`` "calls" the inexistent ``self.utility_1`` and thus fails; it should likely be ``self.utility.utility_1``, which would also be bogus because of the previous issue though.

Comment: Ok, these a really "typos". I tried simplify the problem I have in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in your question is unclear, but just going on your description:

```py
class Parent:

    utility = Utils() # A single instantiation here


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def use_utility_1(self):
        self.utility.utility_1() #Prints Do Something
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, what you want with the `Utils` object is a [singleton](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton), which is probably the cleanest way of implementing what you want. To read about how to implement that in Python3 you can have a look at an example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/singleton-pattern-in-python-a-complete-guide/).

Notice that in the code of your `Parent` class you are not *instantiating* the Utility object, rather you are assigning the return value of `Utils.utility_1` to `utility`. What you probably wanted to do is:

```
class Parent:
    utils = Utils()
```

In this way you can call the utility function both from the Parent class and on the Parent and Child objects:

```
class Utils:
    def log(self, x):
        print("This is x:", x)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
   
    def use_logger(self):
        self.utils.log(self.x)
```

Input:

```
child1 = Child("hello")
child1.use_logger()
                  
child2 = Child("world")
child2.use_logger()
                  
Parent.utils.log("hey there")
        
a_parent = Parent()
a_parent.utils.log("sup"
```

Output:

```
This is x: hello
This is x: world
This is x: hey there
This is x: sup
```

However, using static variables of a class does not allow you to instantiate them by hand.